# Https request using JSON using POST?

Tags: javascript, json, https

How do I connect to a registration endpoint (http:....) using a JSON dictionary with two keys, token (provided) and github (my repository url). This JSON should be sent in the body of an HTTP request.  For token,I must a string with a token. For github, I have to pass in the URL of the repository that I created.

Comment: Take a look at this: [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Thanks,I am doing an API registration challenge. To get started, you’re first going to connect to the registration endpoint. It lives here:

http://challenge.........../api/registerThe registration endpoint expects a JSON dictionary with two keys, token and github. This JSON should be sent in the body of your HTTP request.For token, pass in a string with the token you see above. For github, pass in the URL of the repository you created in the last step.Hint: HTTP has a few types of “methods.” The registration endpoint is going to be expecting you to use POST to send your JSON.

Comment: Split your challenge in little steps. 1 Read the JSON and access it's data. 2 : do HTTP POST for the link provided and see what is returned. 
Try something, it's a challenge.